# Error Starting SQL Agent - Unknown Sysadmin Account

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-agent

I'm running SQL 2012 on my development machine and this morning I started up and ran some tests in Visual Studio, it become apparent that I couldn't connect.

Everything was working fine yesterday and I haven't made any security related changes to my system in my sleep!

In my Error logs I see:

```
SQLServerAgent could not be started (reason: SQLServerAgent must be able to connect to
SQLServer as SysAdmin, but '(Unknown)' is not a member of the SysAdmin role).
```

I haven't made any configuration changes that would effect this (as least to my knowledge).

I can open Management studio using Windows and Sql authentication and run queries.

SQL Server and SQL Server Agent both run under the default LocalSystem account.

Running:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Agent XPs', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Reported:

```
Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Configuration option 'Agent XPs' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
```

Remote Connections is enabled
SQL Server / Windows Authentication is enabled

All the Protocols are enabled:

Shared Memory
TCP/IP
Named Pipes
VIA

I've been reading for a couple of hours on this now and I cannot figure it out.  What's the best course of action now?

Comment: Just as a test, why don't you create a new local account called `local-sqlservice` (can be whatever you want), add this in to the SysAdmin role in SQL Server and set it as the service account for SQL Server  SQL Server Agent. See if it runs.

Comment: Thats saying that the account the sql server agent service is running as is wrong.No idea why from here, but it's saying whatever account it is doesn't map to sa.

Comment: @Tony for sure.  What I don't get is why this has suddenly occurred with no warning.  How do I reapply the mapping of LocalSystem to sa?

Comment: @Barry - Just for simplicity sake I used my own windows login as the account for SQL Server and the SQL Agent and now I have a whole new level of pain ... SQLServerAgent could not be started (reason: This installation of SQL Server Agent is disabled.  The edition of SQL Server that installed this service does not support SQL Server Agent.).

Comment: So you must be using an Express version then? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#RDBMS_mgmt

Comment: Yes I am.  I've just done a complete reinstall and I'm still getting A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Comment: Firewall, may be. As yo how it suddenly happens. All you need is a restart of the service, perhaps after reboot, so the account credentials get validated again. I once saw something similar where the account being used had been killed a year previously. Found out when they moved the box in the server room...

Comment: I ended up doing a clean install ... I spent most of the day on this and got nowhere so killed the install and started again.  All fine now.  Been a long day ... :(